# Query on relationship objects in realm

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have to classes stored using Realm.io (and therefore extending RLMObject) : class A and B, with class A having a property of type B.
I would like to query all objects of class A where A.b.propertyX=something, but I can't get it working. Maybe is it not even possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realm v0.81.0 now supports querying over a relationship. Here's how it works:

`[A objectsWhere:@"b.propertyX == 'something'"]`

or

`[Person objectsWhere:@"ANY dogs.name == 'Alfonso'"]`

Comment: How is this done in Swift? Is `objectsWhere` method on a Realm method? Or is this supposed to be used in a Predicate?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum in Realm Swift you'd use `realm.objects(Person.self).filter("ANY dogs.name == 'Alfonso'")`. See Realm Swift docs on Queries for more details: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#queries

Comment: What to to if I have a property of class A in class A itself. so that it can be a.a.b.propertyX == 'something'  or a.a.a.b.propertyX == 'something' or a.a......a.a.b.propertyX == 'something' and so on. Is it possible to do  in a single fetch with realm?